# DateAdd in control Source

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I keep getting error in the control source

[image]

this is the code I'm using. What I am doing wrong?

`DateAdd(IIf([CalibrationRecord]![UOM]="days","d",IIf([CalibrationRecord]![UOM]="month","m","yyyy")),[CalTimeInterval],[LastCalDate])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking this is in a Form/Report - not a query? But it looks like you're using query syntax to set a field name based on two tables in the query.

If it's a form/report Access only sees the field names - so try eliminating your Table Name `[CalibrationRecord]` from the formula

```
DateAdd(IIf([UOM]="days","d",IIf([UOM]="month","m","yyyy")),[CalTimeInterval],[LastCalDate])
```